# XML Data to CSV

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, xml, csv-simple

Need some quick help as I am not able to get the desired output:

```
2020-05-19 19:03:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><TYPE>RCTRFREQ</TYPE><DN1>99847</DN1><AMOUNT>49</AMOUNT></COMMAND> - 
2020-05-19 19:05:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><PE>RC</PE><DN1>92847</DN1><AMOUNT>19</AMOUNT></COMMAND> - 
2020-05-19 19:05:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><DN1>947</DN1><TYPE>RC</TYPE><AMOUNT>29</AMOUNT></COMMAND> -
```

Required Output:

```
Time,DN1,AMOUNT
2020-05-19 19:03:07,99847,49
2020-05-19 19:05:07,92847,19
2020-05-19 19:05:07,947,29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=",|</?(DN1|AMOUNT)>"; OFS=","; print "Time", "DN1", "AMOUNT" }
    { print $1, $3, $(NF-1) }
' file
Time,DN1,AMOUNT
2020-05-19 19:03:07,99847,49
2020-05-19 19:05:07,92847,19
2020-05-19 19:05:07,947,29
```

The above tells awk to separate the input into fields separated by strings that match the regexp being stored in `FS` (i.e. `,`, `<DN1>`, `</DN1>`, `<AMOUNT>`, and `</AMOUNT>`), and then print the 1st, 3rd, and 2nd-last such fields.

Here's how the above splits each record into fields:

```
$ awk -F',|</?(DN1|AMOUNT)>' '{print "----" ORS $0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, i "/" NF, $i}' file
----
2020-05-19 19:03:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><TYPE>RCTRFREQ</TYPE><DN1>99847</DN1><AMOUNT>49</AMOUNT></COMMAND> -
1 1/6 2020-05-19 19:03:07
1 2/6 135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><TYPE>RCTRFREQ</TYPE>
1 3/6 99847
1 4/6
1 5/6 49
1 6/6 </COMMAND> -
----
2020-05-19 19:05:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><PE>RC</PE><DN1>92847</DN1><AMOUNT>19</AMOUNT></COMMAND> -
2 1/6 2020-05-19 19:05:07
2 2/6 135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><PE>RC</PE>
2 3/6 92847
2 4/6
2 5/6 19
2 6/6 </COMMAND> -
----
2020-05-19 19:05:07,135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND><DN1>947</DN1><TYPE>RC</TYPE><AMOUNT>29</AMOUNT></COMMAND> -
3 1/6 2020-05-19 19:05:07
3 2/6 135 INFO [Container : 8504] [HttpUtil.java]requestXML: <?xml version="1.0"? ><COMMAND>
3 3/6 947
3 4/6 <TYPE>RC</TYPE>
3 5/6 29
3 6/6 </COMMAND> -
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton!!!!! it worked.

Comment: +1 Interesting way to specify field separators. Didn't know that it was possible.

Comment: @Cbhihe yeah a field separator is just an ERE with a couple of twists (e.g. `" "` means ignore all leading/trailing blanks and separate at all remaining chains of blanks).

Comment: Sure. I just had never seen ERE and boolean operators in the specification of FS.  I guess I missed out on the section of `man awk`, that explicitly says that, when it comes to the string value of `FS`, _"ERE tokens or arbitrary expressions, shall be interpreted in the same manner as the rhs of the `~` or the `!~` operators."_

Comment: @EdMorton if I want to add one more tag suppose "TYPE" can you let me know how can we fetch time,DN1,Amount and Tag all 4 together.

Comment: Ask a new question with its own MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged.

Comment: @EdMorton can you please explain this code it will be very useful.

Comment: Sure, which specific part of it is unclear - 1) `FS=",|</?(DN1|AMOUNT)>"`, 2) `OFS=","`, 3) `print "Time", "DN1", "AMOUNT"`, or 4) `print $1, $3, $(NF-1)`

Comment: 1 and 4 please.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain those points and show how the record is decomposed into fields. If you want a more flexible, extensible solution that'll work for any tags in any order of input and can print their values in any order in  the output then ask a new question and make sure you state that as the goal and include the tags in mixed positions in the sample input.

Comment: @EDMorton Thanks a lot!!! Excellent explanation . Helped me to fetch any number of tag I want. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Well-structured lines can be parsed with `sed`:

```
sed -En 's|^([^,]+),.*<DN1>(.+)</DN1>.*<AMOUNT>(.+)</AMOUNT>.*|\1,\2,\3|p' file
```

- `-E` enables extended regular expressions
- `-n` suppresses automatic printing of read lines
- `s|...|___|` searches for line matching the `...` part and replaces them by `___`
- `^([^,]+),` matches the beginning until the first `,` and puts it into `\1`
- `<DN1>(.+)</DN1> matches the`DN1`element and puts its content into`\2`
- `<AMOUNT>(.+)</AMOUNT>` does the same for `AMOUNT`
- `\1,\2,\3`  substitutes the result
- `p` makes sure any matching line gets printed on stdout

Answer (score 0):

can be done with following `awk` and `sed` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="AMOUNT|,|DN1" ;OFS=","}; {print $1,$3,$5}' xmlfile | sed 's/<\|>\|\///g' > output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks !!! can you please explain the code. Also just to highlight tags are not in any specific place.

Comment: my assumption, `DN1` is before `AMOUNT` as in the sample. if not this code cannot be useful, so could you please clarify?

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. `awk '{print $1,$3,$5}' file | sed 's/<\|>\|\///g'` = `awk '{$0=$1 OFS $3 OFS $5; gsub("[<>/]",""); print}' file`.

Answer (score 0):

This case is a little odd to be processed by oneliner and I would stick with processing XML as an XML object not as a string thus I took  Python. It parses date as string and find an XML string to be used to load. This approach gives you more flexibility if you would like to append the script in the future for more nodes from XML or other fields in the input line.

The first argument passed to the script is your input file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_lines():

    file_name = str(sys.argv[1])
    f = open(file_name, 'r')

    return f.readlines()


def print_header():

    print("Time,DN1,AMOUNT")


def process_xml(xml):

    doc = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
    elements = [
            doc.find("DN1").text,
            doc.find("AMOUNT").text
            ]

    return (",").join(elements)


def process_date(line):

    date = line.split()[:2]
    date = " ".join(date).split(",")[0]

    return date


def process_line(line):

    fields = []
    date = process_date(line)
    xml = process_xml(line.split("<?xml version=\"1.0\"? >")[1][:-3])

    fields.append(date)
    fields.append(xml)

    return (",").join(fields)


def process_all(lines):

    print_header()
    for line in lines:
        print(process_line(line))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    lines = get_lines()
    process_all(lines)
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz; can you explain why "this approach gives you more flexibility" ? Cheers.

Comment: Hi cbhihe, maybe "flexible" is just a wrong word I used. It is much more readable for me to add some items to be replaced here in python script than using regular expressions.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: your answer is functional and I like Python very much. However, at worst, encapsulating the accepted answer by @EdMorton in a 5 line shell-script with script arguments as variables for the `awk` logic, is far simpler than calling the heavy cavalry with 6 functions definitions and 2 module imports in 30 some lines. Am I being weird ?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, and I agree with you, but it all depends on the needs, so I presented different approach, finally it's up to the guy who asks the quesitons which solution is more comprehensive for him.